# Facebook Connect Access denied on line 22 all.js in IE7/8

Tags: facebook

I created a very, very simple login page using the exact code that is given in the introduction page of the facebook connect website.  Every time I try to launch to connect through IE I get an error through javascript asking me if I want to debug a permission denied problem on line 22.  Everything works fine in firefox, chrome, etc.

Odd thing is, the same exact error shows up in Hulu the other day when I tried to connect my Hulu account with FB Connect -- the javascript died on a permission denied problem on the same line.  I have tried multiple machines (XP, 7 and Vista) and multiple IE browsers (IE7 and 8), same error.

Here is a copy of my code.

```
<html>
<head>
  <title>My Facebook Login Page</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="fb-root"></div>

  <script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>
  <script>
     FB.init({
        appId:'XXXXXXXXXXX', cookie:true,
        status:true, xfbml:true
     });
  </script>

<fb:login-button perms="email,user_checkins">
     Login with Facebook
  </fb:login-button>


</body>
</html>
```

This page can be viewed here: http://www.thecmmns.com/facebooktest2.html

Obviously the XXXXX thing is an actual ID on the live site.

Any ideas?  I am very surprised I am the only one seeing this since it even happens on Hulu...  Anyone else access Hulu or the above site and get access denied with IE7 or IE 8?  Any ideas how to fix?

Comment: BWT, the settings on facebook is Site URL: http://www.thecmmns.com/, Site Domain: thecmmns.com -- I have tried it will Site Domain both filled out and not filled out.  Also, this page works fine in Firefox, Safari, Chrome, etc on both Mac and PC.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Permission denied error in all.js](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/7280007/permission-denied-error-in-all-js)

Answer (score 0):

Just add this code before `FB.init`:

```
FB.UIServer.setLoadedNode = function (a, b){FB.UIServer._loadedNodes[a.id] = b; }
```

[Read more at my blog](http://blog.develio.us/index.php/2011/12/13/facebook-error-permission-denied-in-all-js-ini-error-cuma-ada-di-ie/).

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
"https://connect.facebook.net/assets.php/en_US/sdk.js"
```

to

```
"https://connect.facebook.com/assets.php/en_US/sdk.js"
```

That will be ok.

It's weird that Facebook doesn't update their document.